# PROXY auto config windows phone 8

Tags: proxy, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to auto configure PROXY in windows phone 8 when my app is installed by the user? maybe settings file is possible, but not sure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

WP8 apps can't change the proxy settings of the device network connections. Apps just get to use the network connections that are already available and connected (and get notified when these change).

Comment: In addition to that, is it possible to redirect user to a webpage that installs a proxy, similar to what is possible on iOS devices?